# Would a sparse NP-Complete language imply L = NP?

Tags: np-complete, p-vs-np

Would a sparse NP-Complete language imply L = NP?

**Update: Thanks to Noah Schweber for clear and comprehensive answer. Having thought about it more, one would need a logspace reduction from NP-complete to L-complete for NP=L. [4] below does not directly address this.**

Here is my proof attempt:

[1] Assume there exists a (sparse NP-Complete language).

> Mahaney's theorem is a theorem in computational complexity theory proven by Stephen Mahaney that states that if any sparse language is NP-Complete, then P=NP.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahaney%27s_theorem

[2] In other words, (sparse NP-Complete language) implies (P = NP).

[3] From [1] and [2] (P = NP).

[4] (P = NP) implies (P-complete = NP-complete).

[5] From [3] and [4] (P-complete = NP-complete).

[6] From [1] and [5] there exists a (sparse P-Complete language)

> In 1999, Jin-Yi Cai and D. Sivakumar, building on work by Ogihara, showed that if there exists a sparse P-complete problem, then L = P."

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_language

[7] In other words, (sparse P-complete problem) implies (L = P).

[8] From [6] and [7] (L = P).

[9] From [3] and [8] (L = NP).

Comment: I don’t see any question here.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I added a question to the body

Answer (score 5):

Your claim [4] is wrong - the issue is with the term "$X$-complete" for a complexity class $X$.

Stricly speaking, barring specific convention the phrase "$X$-completeness" doesn't pin down a single notion: we also need to specify the **reducibility notion** involved. For example, [Cai/Sivakumar](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022000098916154?via%3Dihub) look at P-completeness with respect to **logspace** and **NC** many-one reductions, while "NP-complete" refers to **polynomial-time** many-one reductions. Changing the reducibility notion changes the completeness (and hardness) notion - for a silly example, everything in P is NP-complete with respect to exponential-time Turing reductions.

So the implication "P=NP implies P-complete=NP-complete" is a non-sequitur, since the implicit reducibility notions are different. P=NP **does** imply (say) "P-complete w/r/t logspace reductions = NP-complete w/r/t logspace reductions," but that's a completely different thing.

Comment: Sure, you would need a log-space reduction to prove L=P, for example? Wouldn't P=NP imply a polynomial time reduction from a NP-complete problem to a P-complete problem?

Comment: I thought X-complete means "all problems in X can be reduced to X using X's (time and space) resources" where "using X's resources" is the "reproducibility notion". In this case, if P=NP, then any problem in NP could be reduced to a P-complete problem using polynomial time (and thus polynomial space if we're being precise)

Comment: @WordsLikeJared "Wouldn't P=NP imply a polynomial time reduction from a NP-complete problem to a P-complete problem? " Yes (that's the definition - and "P-complete" can just be replaced with "any problem in P"), but I don't see how that's relevant. "I thought X-complete means "all problems in X can be reduced to X using X's (time and space) resources" where "using X's resources" is the "reproducibility notion"." No, it doesn't. E.g. we can talk about something being EXPTIME-complete with respect to polynomial-time many-one reductions.

Comment: Sorry I was blind. I see now. Logspace reduction for P-complete. Didn't realize that. Thank you for your patience!!!

Comment: @WordsLikeJared All good, this stuff's tricky at first (or at least it was for me). Glad I could help!

Comment: I thought more about it. Are you saying P=NP implies two P-completes: a P-logspace-complete and a P-polynomial-complete? If there are different notions of "complete" for a complexity class, this makes sense.

Comment: @WordsLikeJared P=NP has nothing to do with it. There are, full stop, several different completeness notions: "P-complete for logspace many-one reductions," "P-complete for polynomial-time many-one reductions" (that's trivially just P itself), "P-complete for logspace Turing reductions," etc. When two such notions coincide is in general a very hard problem - for example, "NP-complete for polynomial-time many-one reductions" and "NP-complete for exptime many-one reductions" coincide iff P=NP, since the latter is trivially NP itself - but the **general plurality** of completenesses is immediate.

Comment: (The same is true for hardness, by the way: "X-hard for Y reductions" and "X-hard for Z reductions" are a priori different notions.)